# CoreOS persistant data storage ( creation + backup + restore )?

Tags: backup, mount, docker, data-recovery, coreos

Im planning to move my whole server stack to coreOS and using docker.
The problem is currently there seems to be no good solutions to create a persistant data storage , back it up and easily restore it when needed?

I know one can create inside the cloud-config.yml a data mount but are there opensource solutions to handle the whole chain of

1) creation
2) backup
3) easy restore ( for example on new coreOS image, perhaps even from the cloud-config.yaml )

Comment: So I found this : http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/02/20/config-mount-nfs-coreos/ suggesting using an remote NFS storage, it will have latency and extra costs. Preferrable I would use a data volume on the coreOS system itself that would be backed up and somehow easily restorable

Comment: Would Flocker with EBS be a solution? I wonder if not more people have this problem at the moment. Or should I just drop the idea of coreOS? I like it to be lean and read only it feels more secure and clean. No easy hacking into and no packages or tools running on it that takes many hours of tuning and disabling. Anyone shares my pain point and have found a solution? I like the idea of flocker but not yet ready for prime time. just a storage volume that docker could write to under coreOS would be OK for the next couple of months / year untill everything gets more mature.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to build a container for rsnapshot or similar tool that mounts your data store as a volume. Rsnapshot cannot push backups to another host but you could sync to a directory that's on a remote file system. A restore from an rsnapshot backup is a simple rsync and should be simple to trigger from cloud-init.

Another option is to roll a container running a client for bacula or amanda that, again, mounts your data directory as a volume. The restore might be a bit trickier but it has the advantage of having all of your backups managed from a single point.